# Issues using fxruby on OS X Mavericks

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-mavericks, fxruby

I am trying to install the fxruby gem, but when I try to require it, I get this error message:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- fox16
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0 p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I have homebrew, command line tools, and fox installed on my system. I am using ruby 2.0.0 on OS X Mavericks. Any tips?

Comment: How did you even install this? I am stuck at `sudo gem install fxruby`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but

turns out mavericks needs ruby 2.1 (I believe).

try entering these lines

```
gem source -r https://rubygems.org/

gem source -a http://rubygems.org/

sudo gem install fxruby
```

Got this information from an update note on this document (same process)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/db3fy100u0kaz63/Creating_an_FXRuby_Build_Environment_in_Lion.rtf